# PowerShell Optimize Performance

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Let me preface this by saying I'm not a PowerShell expert by any means. I've written the script below, which gives the correct results, but the performance is abysmal. It is taking > 5 minutes to execute, and I know there is a more efficient way to achieve the same result. I'm hoping for some help in refactoring this script to optimize performance as much as possible.

Summary of requirement: Pull a list of users from MS Graph who are in these 4 security groups (they may be a member in more than one group) and add a column to the user details output to indicate a "Yes/No" on whether they are a member of each of the 4 groups respectively.

Desired Output:

> ```
> DisplayName       : John Smith
> Id                : 1234567890
> Mail              : johnsmith@abc.com
> UserPrincipalName : johnsmith@abc.com
> JobTitle          : Manager
> Group1             : Yes
> Group2             : Yes
> Group3             : No
> Group4             : No
> ```

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions
#Group List
$groups = @{
    GroupIds = @(
        '123456789' #Group 1 
        '987654321' #Group 2
        '154637485' #Group 3
        '856453756' #Group 4
    )
}
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes 'User.Read.All', 'Group.ReadWrite.All'

$tmSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku -All | Where-Object SkuPartNumber -EQ 'SKU1'

$tmUsers = Get-MgUser -Filter "assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq $($tmsku.SkuId) )" -ConsistencyLevel eventual -CountVariable tmlicensedUserCount -All | Select-Object 'DisplayName', 'Id', 'Mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'JobTitle' 
$tmUsers | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Group1 -NotePropertyValue No
$tmUsers | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Group2 -NotePropertyValue No
$tmUsers | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Group3 -NotePropertyValue No
$tmUsers | Add-Member -NotePropertyName Group4 -NotePropertyValue No

Write-Host "Found $tmlicensedUserCount users."

foreach ($teammemberuser in $tmUsers) {

    $groupList = Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup -UserId $teammemberuser.Id -BodyParameter $groups 
    if ($groupList -contains '123456789') {
        $teammemberuser.'Group1' = 'Yes'
    }
    if ($groupList -contains '987654321') {
        $teammemberuser.'Group2' = 'Yes'
    }
    if ($groupList -contains '154637485') {
        $teammemberuser.'Group3' = 'Yes'
    }
    if ($groupList -contains '856453756') {
        $teammemberuser.'Group4' = 'Yes'
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this as a new answer as I think the previous one is worth keeping for future readers. The issue with the previous answer, as we have learnt with OP (*see extensive comment section*), using [`$expand=memberOf` and `$expand=transitiveMemberOf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters?tabs=http#expand-parameter) doesn't bring the user's complete membership so this answer approaches the problem a different way while trying to keep it efficient.

[image: doc]

The main idea, as explained in the previous answer, is to try and reduce the number of Graph calls as much as possible. This is the main reason why your current code is slow. The approach of this answer is to query the groups and get their [`transitiveMembers`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-transitivemembers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) that **are users** (`transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user`) **where** those users have the target license assigned (`assignedLicenses/any(e: e/skuId eq xxx-xx-xxx-xxx)`) and, for each user, project their `Id` (`$select=id`).

Then, we follow with the same approach as in your code, get all users having the assigned license but for the comparison we can check if each user exists in the `HashShet<T>` containing all members `Id` of each group.

For reference, the group members query might be doable with `Get-MgGroupMember` that should make the code less extensive but I personally don't use the cmdlets in the Graph Module except for [`Invoke-MgGraphRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.authentication/invoke-mggraphrequest?view=graph-powershell-1.0) so I honestly have no idea if it's possible and how to do it with that cmdlet.

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web

# this function handles paging,
# see for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging
function Get-GroupMembersId {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param([string] $uri)

    do {
        $response = Invoke-MgGraphRequest GET $uri -Headers @{ ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual' }
        $uri = $response.'@odata.nextLink'
        if ($null -ne $response.value) {
            $response.value.Id
        }
    }
    while ($uri)
}

# the target Sku here
$tmSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku .....

# construct the Uri, the idea here will be to get all members of each group
# in `$groups.Keys` where the members of each group has the assigned license
# equal to `$tmsku.SkuId` and, for each user, project their Id
$query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::ParseQueryString('')
$query['$count'] = 'true'
$query['$filter'] = 'assignedLicenses/any(e: e/skuId eq {0})' -f $tmsku.SkuId
$query['$select'] = 'id'
$uri = [System.UriBuilder] 'https://graph.microsoft.com'
$uri.Query = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($query.ToString())

$groups = [ordered]@{
    # key   = The property name in your result object
    # value = The Group Id (the GUID that identifies it)
    Group1 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
    Group2 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
    Group3 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
}

# this map will have:
# key   = The property name in your result object (group1, group2...)
# value = The Hashset<Guid> containing the user Ids members of each group
$map = [ordered]@{}
$groups.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
    # using `transitiveMembers` for recursive call (use just `members` for direct)
    $uri.Path = 'v1.0/groups/{0}/transitiveMembers/microsoft.graph.user' -f $_.Value
    $map[$_.Key] = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[guid]] @(Get-GroupMembersId $uri.Uri.ToString())
}

# now we continue with the same approach as in the previous answer but here
# we don't need to `ExpandProperty = 'memberOf'` because we already have all
# members of each group in `$map`
$getMgUserSplat = @{
    Filter           = "assignedLicenses/any(x: x/skuId eq $($tmsku.SkuId))"
    Select           = 'DisplayName', 'Id', 'Mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'JobTitle'
    All              = $true
}

$users = Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat

$result = foreach ($user in $users) {
    $outObject = [ordered]@{
        DisplayName       = $user.DisplayName
        Id                = $user.Id
        Mail              = $user.Mail
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        JobTitle          = $user.JobTitle
    }

    foreach ($group in $map.GetEnumerator()) {
        # now here remember, `$group.Key` is the group name that
        # will later on be the Property Name of your object
        # and `$group.Value` is a HashSet<Guid> of all members of that group
        # so we can use its `.Contains` method for a super fast search
        $outObject[$group.Key] = $group.Value.Contains($user.Id)
    }

    [pscustomobject] $outObject
}

$result
```

Comment: This works really well. It is fast and accurate. Thank you again for all your support and efforts, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Mayhem i'm glad it was helpful. Clearly this solution won't be as fast as the first one but should be accurate. Is it faster than what you had before tho? I'm tempted to raise a MSFT ticket to have them clarify why `$expand=memberOf` don't return all the direct membership. Tired of their bs.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few improvements you could make to make your code more efficient.

The key points are:

1. Avoid `Add-Member` at all costs, attaching note properties to an existing object is already expensive and this cmdlet makes it even more expensive
2. Reduce the amount of Graph calls, currently, you're querying Graph to get the users that meet your `-Filter` condition, and then per each user, you're making a Graph call to check if they're members of the groups.
   Instead, make a single call to Graph, get the users that meet your `-Filter` but also get their membership with `-ExpandProperty memberOf`. You can then use that membership (the `.MemberOf` property) to do the checks.
3. Use `-Select` to reduce the amount of properties you want Graph to return.

```bash
$tmSku = Get-MgSubscribedSku .....

$groups = [ordered]@{
    # key   = The property name in your result object
    # value = The Group Id (the GUID that identifies it)
    Group1 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
    Group2 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
    Group3 = 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxx'
}

$getMgUserSplat = @{
    Filter           = "assignedLicenses/any(x: x/skuId eq $($tmsku.SkuId))"
    ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'
    CountVariable    = 'count'
    Select           = 'DisplayName', 'Id', 'Mail', 'UserPrincipalName', 'JobTitle', 'MemberOf'
    ExpandProperty   = 'memberOf'
    All              = $true
}

$users = Get-MgUser @getMgUserSplat

$result = foreach ($user in $users) {
    # use a `Hashset<T>` so we have the `.Contains` method from it
    # (fast stuff)
    [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[guid]] $membership = @($user.MemberOf.Id)
    $outObject = [ordered]@{
        DisplayName       = $user.DisplayName
        Id                = $user.Id
        Mail              = $user.Mail
        UserPrincipalName = $user.UserPrincipalName
        JobTitle          = $user.JobTitle
    }

    foreach ($group in $groups.GetEnumerator()) {
        # `.Contains` here outputs a bool (true / false)
        # you can however add a condition here, if true then 'Yes', else 'No'
        $outObject[$group.Key] = $membership.Contains($group.Value)
    }

    [pscustomobject] $outObject
}

$result
```

Comment: This is SO much faster, thank you! I seem to be getting all false values back for the group associations in the result set, so I'm stepping through to see where things aren't working as expected.

Comment: Hi @Mayhem, glad this answer was helpful. Thinking about false values back, could you clarify on that? I'm thinking maybe the issue is that `Expand = memberOf` only brings direct group membership, in other words its not recursive. There is also `transitiveMemberOf` for recursive but that will be much slower ofc (but this might be the reason of false values you're seeing)

Comment: For context, open this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta and search for `List memberOf` and `List transitiveMemberOf` just below that one

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  The script is pulling back ~2500 user records, and indicating that none of these users are a members of any group (all user group values = false), which I know is not valid. I tried replacing with the transitive approach, but same result. When I run $users.memberOf, it is returning a massive list of GUIDs, so I feel like that part is working as expected and is pulling the list of groups that each user is a member of. Maybe there is something wrong with the matching further down in the script.

Comment: @Mayhem and you're 100% that the value of the hashtable keys in `$groups` (i.e.: `Group1 = 'GROUP GUID HERE'`) are the actual Group Ids?

Comment: In case it matters, the vast majority of the users I'd be pulling in this script have this license SKU assigned via group license assignment (i.e. membership in the group). Only a small number of the users have a direct license SKU assignment.

Comment: I've triple checked the group GUID values, and they are correct. I'm thinking the issue lies in the way the license SKU is being interpreted. Needs to handle both direct and group assignment of the respective license SKU.

Comment: The SKU seems to be right. Things I've confirmed:

1. User list is correct 2660 users. 
2. MemberOf Expansion is seemingly correct 51K records, AND contains all 4 of my group IDs.  Confirmed using $users.MemberOf.Id.Contains("xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx")

Comment: @Mayhem so the code is working? im lost already

Comment: Sorry, I know that was confusing. The code is not working. It seems to be working as expected up until the group evaluation. The list of users and their group membership is being pulled correctly, but the comparison to check the groups is not working as expected.

Comment: @Mayhem easier way to debug that, pick a user that you know is a member of one of the groups and store it in `$user`, then do `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[guid]] $membership = @($user.MemberOf.Id)` and inspect `$membership`, once you confirmed the guids are there, try `$membership.Contains('xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx')` where `xxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx` is a Value in your `$groups` hashtable. That should ofc output `$true`

Comment: I filtered down to one user that I confirmed is in one of the groups, checked the $membership object, and did NOT find this group. It looks like it isn't pulling all group memberships for some reason.

Comment: @Mayhem even using `transitiveMemberOf` instead of `memberOf` ?

Comment: Correct, I tried both, and the same list of groups is being pulled regardless of which method I use.

Comment: When I use Get-MgUserMemberOf with my test user GUID, I'm getting the complete and proper list of groups. For some reason I'm getting a limited set when using Get-MgUser with MemberOf/TransitiveMemberOf expansion.

Comment: @Mayhem yep thats what I'm seeing too. Wasn't aware of this and I don't see it documented either, this might be a bug. So `Get-MgUserMemberOf` calls this API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http which targets only 1 specific user and does pagination based on the amount of groups. Welp thats a downer, I guess you will need make an API call per user. I can share a different version of the code with parallelism but that would require pwsh 7+

Comment: Thank you SO much for all your efforts here, I really appreciate it. If there are any optimizations that I can make to my existing code without the shift to this alternative method, that would be helpful. Otherwise, I'll just have to be patient and use what I've currently got.

Comment: @Mayhem sure I can do a different version similar but using `Confirm-MgUserMemberGroup` and `ForEach-Object -Parallel` but that would require pwsh 7+

Comment: I can get the latest version no problem.

Comment: @Mayhem I wonder if it wouldn't be faster to get all members of each group and then check if they have that license. How big are these groups and how many groups are you actually checking ?

Comment: That absolutely could be true. I'm checking maximum 4 groups, with the largest group having no more than 3100 members.

Comment: @Mayhem ok so to confirm, you want any user that is a memberOf any of the groups in a list that also have a specific license assigned right? Do you need direct memberOf or recursive memberOf ?

Comment: I need a list of user details for users that have a specific license SKU either assigned directly or via group assignment,  along with a column added for each group which is a true/false of whether that user is a member of the respective group. If they have a direct license assignment, I expect all group fields to be false as that user would not be a member of any group and instead has a direct license. There could be exceptions, which is also what this list will help me find.